# How to access Monero functions on Android?

Tags: mymonero, build, android-wallet, c++, android

I am trying to run Monero on Android. Basically I want to access C++ core functions like `make_ring_signature` and `create_transaction` etc on Android.

I followed these two links:

1. https://forum.getmonero.org/5/support/87643/building-monero-v0-10-3-1-for-android
2. https://github.com/m2049r/xmrwallet/blob/master/doc/BUILDING-external-libs.md

But these links didn't help me because I am getting lots of errors and also not enough explanation is given.

Also, I tried to build the mymonero-app-android project and it didn't build on my machine either.

Can somebody please give concise instructions on how to build a Monero project on Android, including how to build the boost libraries properly using Android NDK?

Comment: If you're having trouble building [xmrwallet](https://github.com/m2049r/xmrwallet/) have you tried raising an [issue](https://github.com/m2049r/xmrwallet/issues)?

Comment: No, I haven't raised any issue yet.

Comment: If you're following their instructions to the letter and they're not working, that's the place to start.